# how to add jquery to wordpress

Tags: theme-development, jquery

Hello I am trying to enable jquery to my wordpress website. So far i have searched the internet for something that works but nothing helped me.

This is my jquery script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
alert('test');
    });
```

And this is what i have in my functions php

```
   <?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
    function add_my_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'jquerydemo', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquerdemo.js', // this is the location of your script file
            array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
        );
    }
    ?>
```

These are my other files
header.php

```
<html>
<head>
<?php

wp_head();
?>
<title>Stumble</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url')?>">

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header class="site-header">
<h1>HEADER</h1>
<div id="dropDownButton">
</div>
<nav class="site-nav col-12 col-m-12">
<?php wp_nav_menu( $args);?>
</nav>
</header>
<?php
$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary'
);
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php get_header();?>
<div id="main">
<div id="content">
<h1>Main Area</h1>
<?php if (have_posts() ) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php if (is_single()){
echo "<h4>Posted on " ;the_time('Y,j,F'); echo"</h4>";
} ?>
<p><?php the_content(_('(more...)')) ?></p>
<hr> <?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.') ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
</div>
<div id="delimiter">
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

footer.php

```
<div id="footer">
<?php

wp_footer();
?>
<h1>FOOTER</h1>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Go to you JS console in browser and see what error it's throwing. Then report back.

Comment: It doesn't say anything

Comment: Then go to your themes page source and search for `jquerdemo.js` file. See if it has been called or not. I mean go to source from browser.

Comment: I just tested your code. It's perfectly working on my WordPress installation. You better clear your cache. Then test again.

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a template which i made it's not the default ones

Comment: Please update your question with your template code.

Comment: I checked the source and it doesn't look like it's being included

Comment: I updated my question with the other files in my template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found your problem. In your `header.php` file you've not put `wp_head()` and also on your `footer.php` you've missed `wp_footer()`. Where actually the scripts and style get hooked. Please add those `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` to `header.php` and `footer.php` respectively. If you're confused how and where you in those files you need to add the functions please have look on any WordPress default theme's source. You'll get an idea.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I added <?php
do_action( 'wp_head');
?> at the beggining of the <head> but now it shows this error 
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'hook_javascript' not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 298

Comment: Not `do_action`. Use only `wp_head()` and also do `wp_footer()` at footer.

Comment: at first i used only <?php wp_head() ?> and <?php the_wpfooter() ?> but it still gave the same error

Comment: i updated the code i have in the main post

Comment: The problem was in one of my plugins . I was able to fix it , thank you for your help